# Getting no transaction in progress with multiple datasources with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, transactions, multiple-databases

Running Spring Boot version 2.3.0 with two datasources configured. Am getting the below exception when trying to save an entity to the DB. This same code was working with single datasource. We have followed the setup for multiple datasources found here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Any idea what could be happening or why it's not able to find a transaction?

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:403)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:154)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy190.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source)
    at com.xyz.service.KeyHelperService.createKey(KeyHelperService.java:137)
    at com.xyz.service.KeyHelperService.lambda$0(KeyHelperService.java:86)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at com.xyz.service.KeyHelperService.createAndRotateKey(KeyHelperService.java:76)
    at com.xyz.service.KeyHelperService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6668f0c7.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
```

code snippet of KeyHelperService at line where exception happens:

```
@Audited(...)
@PreAuthorize(...)
@Transactional
public EncryptionKeyMetadata createKey() {
    ...
    Entity e = new Entity();
    ...
    EncryptionKeyMetadata key = keyMetadataRepo.saveAndFlush(e);
    return key;
}
```

The primary datasource configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public class DataSourceConfigWrite extends HikariConfig {

    @Autowired
    private HikariWriteProperties hikariWriteProperties;

    @Autowired
    private HibernateConfig hibernateConfig;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setHikariProps() {
        setPoolName(hikariWriteProperties.getPoolName());
        setMinimumIdle(hikariWriteProperties.getMinimumIdle());
        setMaximumPoolSize(hikariWriteProperties.getMaximumPoolSize());
        setIdleTimeout(hikariWriteProperties.getIdleTimeout());
    }

    @Bean(name = "writeDataSource")
    @Primary
    public HikariDataSource dataSourceWrite() {
        return new HikariDataSource(this);
    }


    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryWrite")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryWrite(
            final @Qualifier("writeDataSource") HikariDataSource dataSourceWrite) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setJpaDialect(new HibernateExtendedJpaDialect());
        DataSourceReadWriteUtil.setEntityManagerProperties(entityManager, dataSourceWrite, hikariWriteProperties.getPackageNames(), hikariWriteProperties.getType(), hibernateConfig);
        return entityManager;
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerWrite(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryWrite") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryWrite) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactoryWrite);
    }
}
```

DataSourceConfig snippet:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryWrite",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerWrite",
        basePackages = {"com.xyz.db.repo"}
)
public class CustomDataSourceConfigWrite {
}
```

application.yml snippet:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
      hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: UTC
  main:
    banner-mode: "off"
  datasource-read:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: 'jdbc:mysql://${db.host:localhost}:${db.port:3336}/xyz_n'
    jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:mysql://${db.host:localhost}:${db.port:3336}/xyz_n'
    username: xyz_n
    password: xyz_n
    platform: mysql
    hikari:
      idle-timeout: 10000
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      minimum-idle: 5
      pool-name: ReadHikariPool
      package-Names: com.xyz.db.repo
      type: read
  datasource:
    url: 'jdbc:mysql://${db.host:localhost}:${db.port:3336}/xyz'
    jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:mysql://${db.host:localhost}:${db.port:3336}/xyz'
    username: xyz
    password: xyz
    initialSize: 5
    minIdle: 5
    maxActive: 30
    maxIdle: 30
    maxWait: 1000000
    defaultAutoCommit: false
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
    testOnBorrow: true
    testWhileIdle: true
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 10000
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 30000
    jmxEnabled: true
    removeAbandonedTimeout: 120
    removeAbandoned: true
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 100
      minimum-idle: 5
      connection-timeout: 30000
      max-lifetime: 5000
      idle-timeout: 1000
      pool-name: WriteHikariPool
      package-Names: com.xyz.db.repo
      type: write
```

Comment: @Transactional annotation, which package are you refering, javax or spring ?

Comment: @hoken, Were you able to solve this issue?